# Setting value to nested object not working in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript so appologies if this is a stupid question. I'm trying to save the value of a returned object to a nested property in an object of type any. However, its not allowing me so could anyone enlighten me on my error.

```
  sharedData:any;

  constructor(private menuService: MenuService) { }

  addToBasket(item:any): void {
    this.sharedData.basketList.push(item);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedData.menu = this.menuService.getMenu();
  }
```

It works fine when I have it as `this.menu = this.menuService.getMenu();`

Answer (score 2):

sharedData is not initialized with anything. from your code I would expect it to be

```
 sharedData:any = {
  basketList: []
 };
```

at least the lines you provided would run well and data would be stored in `sharedData`

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't expect a reply within 2 mins to be honest but it's really appreciated. That fixed everything thank you again.